# How to create auto increment ID field for two separate tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (A and B) and I want each record in these tables to have an unique ID (id_C). How do I do that?

```
TABLE_A:

id_A | id_C
 1      1
 2      3

TABLE_B:

id_B | id_C
 1      2
 2      4
```

PS. I was thinking about something like this:

```
create table c(
    id_c int not null auto_increment,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_c)
);

create table a(
    id_a int not null auto_increment,
    a_c  int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_a),
    FOREIGN KEY (a_c) REFERENCES c(id_c)
);

create table b(
    id_b int not null auto_increment,
    b_c  int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_b),
    FOREIGN KEY (b_c) REFERENCES c(id_c)
);
```

Comment: Do you want `id_C` to appear only once in table A (and only once in table B)? And never on both?

Comment: I want id_C to be unique for every record (no matter if it's from A or B)

Answer (score 0):

Create a table which contains your IDs and make it an auto-incrementing primary key. Use this table to generate unique ids and reference them with foreign key constraints from the other tables. I think this is what you suggested in your question.

Another alternative is to use a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier).